# JS - Array.prototype.clone adds an element to all arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have implemented a simple method to clone an array.

```
Array.prototype.clone = function () {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
};
```

If I use this code, all arrays in my application have the last element that is this clone function!

[image]

Any ideas? xD

Thank you.

Comment: This is expected since you are extending the Array prototype object.

Comment: I don't see it in the array, it is on prototype. Also note that the length of array is `4` having four elements, `clone` is not defined on that array. Why did you _implemented a simple method to clone_ when you could use `.slice(0)` to create copy of an array?

Comment: @Tushar Thank you, but in the latest version of Chrome .slice(0) doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your function to non enumarable.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'clone', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the **editor console** that you are using. It may show the **customised function** (clone function)in the index area and not as a native method in array prototype section.It **not a thing to be worried** as the index is **4** it takes only the elements upto index **0 to 3**.

[The Screenshot of Customized function in the prototype section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRCkY.png)